# Copying files with shutil.copy matching some age and extension with same tree folder pattern as source

Tags: python, copy, backup, directory, shutil

This code should backup new files in defined list of folders. It should be done every hour and another code clears the the target folders of old files.

First I define time, if any file in the folder is older then 3 days it will not copy it.

Source_pole is list of files to copy from.

Destination_root is the target to copy to, where driveName is the letter of backup media.

I also want to copy just *.txt files from C:\folder, so that is why files_pattern is defined.
But right now I just want to copy to work ok.

The function works OK, it copies just those new files.

BUT it takes all files from the source_pole that match and copies them all in destination_root without folders, but I want them in exact folders as they were in source.

I know shutil.copytree would work better, but this is supposed to be backup script which will run every hour and I don't know how to deal with errors that the folders already exists.

os.walk(root_path) returns dirnames of source files in list and I need if the folder does not exists then os.makedirs(that folder), right? But how?

It seems I am writing something similiar to shutil.copytree (http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#copytree-example)

```
cas_dny = 3
#prepocitej dny na hodiny a pak na sekundy
cas_sekundy = cas_dny * 24 * 3600

source_pole = [
'c:\\folder\\export',
'c:\\folder\\log',
'c:\\folder\\import',
]

destination_root = driveName+'\autobackup'

excluded_subdirs = ['_backup'] # subdir to exclude from copy
files_patterns_root = ['*.txt']
files_patterns = ['*.*']

def CopyFiles ():
    for root_path in source_pole:
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_path):
            for dir in excluded_subdirs:
                if dir in dirnames:
                    dirnames.remove(dir) # remove the dir from the subdirs to visit
            for filename in filenames:
                vlastnosti = os.stat(os.path.join(root,filename))
                cas_pristupu = vlastnosti.st_mtime
                now = time.time()
                timedelta = now - cas_pristupu
                if timedelta < cas_sekundy
                    print 'Soubor', os.path.join(root,filename), u'je mladší jak', cas_dny ,u'dny | Tento soubor zkopíruju\n---'
                    for pattern in files_patterns:
                        for thefile in fnmatch.filter(filenames, pattern): # filter the files to copy
                            shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root, thefile), destination_root) #copy file
```

EDIT1:
For:

```
 source_pole = [
'c:\\folder\\bin\\export',
'c:\\folder\\bin\\log',
'c:\\folder\\bin\\import',
]
```

works

```
for dir in excluded_subdirs:
    destionatin_path = os.path.join(destination_root, os.path.relpath(root)).replace ('..\..\..\\','')
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(destination_root, os.path.relpath(root)).replace ('..\..\..\\',''))
    except OSError as e:
        print e
...
...
...
shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root, thefile), destination_path) #copy file
```

but if I choosed another file paths in source_pole I would have to change string at replace...

There must be better way to create same tree structure at destination, this is messy.

EDIT2:
So I just edited shutil.copytree function and added if for age of file, matching patterns, not to overwrite same files and to write read only files as writable. It works good for my use, only its not very fast (about 2MB/s), but I am not happy with it as in shutil.py there is "Consider this example code rather than the ultimate tool." in copytree function.

Much bigger problem is when the function stumbles on file that is hidden like  ~$* files when opening *.docx files and etc it ends with Error 13: Permission Denied and I was unable to except this error. I just use shutil.ignore_patterns('~$*') in ignore parametr to avoid it. Any idea where might be the error?

BTW: I wanted to make folders argument to copy files only in certain levels, but only way I can think of is to count '\' in src and when it reaches certain '\' count then stop. Any better ideas?

```
#for logging purposes
copiedfiles = 0

def kopytree(src, dst, pattern, folders=True, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    global copiedfiles
    global porovnej
    # if src does not exist, function ends
    if not os.path.exists(src):
        print u'Neexistující složka'
        return
    # names writes list of dirs and files in src
    names = os.listdir(src)
    errors = []
    # if for deleting unwanted in names
    if ignore is not None:
        ignored_names = ignore(src, names)
    else:
        ignored_names = set()
    for name in names:
        if name in ignored_names:
            continue
        # fullpaths
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        # get last modified time
        try:
            cas_pristupu = os.stat(srcname).st_mtime
        except IOError as e:
            print e
            print 'Nepodarilo se zjistit vlastnosti souboru'
            logger.warning('U souboru %s se nepodarilo zjistit vlastnoti souboru' % srcname)
        now = time.time()
        # timedelta = age of file in s
        timedelta = now - cas_pristupu
        if timedelta < cas_sekundy:
            # if file is younger then cas_sekundy continue in copy
            try:
                os.makedirs(dst)
            except OSError as e:
                pass
            # if file already exists and they match, then dont overwrite them
            porovnej = False
            try:
                if os.path.isfile(srcname) and os.path.exists(dstname):
                    porovnej = filecmp.cmp(srcname,dstname)
            except WindowsError as e:
                pass
            except IOError as f:
                print f
            # if they match, end
            if porovnej == True:
                print '\nSoubory', srcname,'|', dstname,' se zdaji byt stejne'
                del porovnej
                continue
            # if they dont, copy
            else:
                try:
                    if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
                        linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
                        os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
                    # if folders=True then copy also folders
                    elif os.path.isdir(srcname) and folders:
                        kopytree(srcname, dstname, pattern, folders, symlinks, ignore)
                    # pokud souhlasi s dodanym filtrem, tak kopiruje
                    elif fnmatch.fnmatch(srcname, pattern):
                        copiedfiles += 1
                        print u'Kopíruji soubor', srcname, 'do', dstname
                        shutil.copy2(srcname, dstname)
                # XXX What about devices, sockets etc.?
                except (IOError, os.error) as why:
                    logger.warning('Soubor %s se nepodarilo zkopirovat' % srcname)
                    errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
                # catch the Error from the recursive copytree so that we can
                # continue with other files
                except Error as err:
                    errors.extend(err.args[0])
                # if source file is read only, then write them as writable so they could be deleted later
                try:
                    fileAtt = os.stat(srcname)[stat.ST_MODE]
                    if not fileAtt & stat.S_IWRITE:
                        logger.info ('Soubor %s je ke cteni, na cilove slozce ho udelam zapisovatelnym' % srcname)
                        print 'zdrojovy soubor je ke cteni, u ciloveho ho udelam zapisovatelnym'
                        os.chmod(dstname, stat.S_IWRITE)
                except IOError as e:
                    print e
    #copies permissions stats
    try:
        shutil.copystat(src, dst)
    except WindowsError:
        # can't copy file access times on Windows
        pass
    except OSError as why:
        errors.extend((src, dst, str(why)))
    if errors:
        raise Error(errors)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dest_path = os.path.join(destination_root, root)
os.makedirs(dest_path)
shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root, thefile), dest_path)
```

Comment: Thanks.
os.path.join(destination_root, root) gives me correct path at the destination. But when I use it anywhere in for, it gives me same path as source.